# TextEditingController not working with GetX

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

What I am doing wrong?

```
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

class TextControllers extends GetxController {
  Rx<TextEditingController> userInputController = TextEditingController().obs;
}
```

- Error: Type 'TextEditingController' not found.
  Rx<TextEditingController> userInputController = TextEditingController().obs;

I am using:

```
dependencies:
  get: ^4.6.5
```

Comment: can I ask why you're trying to make the TextEditingController an observable?

Comment: I want to populate the TextField which is in a class, from another class

Comment: you can achieve it without using Rx on it just use userInputController.text ="value", then execute an update(), just make sure the GetxController where the userInputController isn't deleted when you're on other screen

Comment: I figure it out. I just had to  `import 'package:flutter/material.dart';`  as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to change the text asap text controller has new text.
for that, you should make an obs `String`.

```
RxString text = ''.obs;
```

then in the `onChanged` property, assign the `TextField` value to it, like this:

```
TextField(
    onChanged: (value) {
      text.value = value;
    },
    );
```

Comment: @Gwhyyy onChange is a Function it has a syntax of onChange:(){}. Isn't my way was correct?

Comment: onChange:(){} is not a valid syntax for functions, can you guide me where you saw this

Comment: oh, wait did you mean the onChanged property of a TextField ??

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use this way:

```
  var sentence = <sentences>[].obs;
  Rx<TextEditingController> titleController =
      TextEditingController(text: "").obs;

  @override
  void onReady() {
    getSingleSentence("55");
    super.onReady();
  }

  void getSingleSentence(String id) async {
    var tmp = await Api.getSingleEnglish(id);
    sentence.value = [sentences.fromJson(tmp.data)];
    titleController.value =
        TextEditingController(text: sentence[0].original.toString());
  }
}
```